# Will smoking about 10 cigarettes per year over about 50 years virtually do anything to your health?

Tags: smoking, lasting-effects-duration, risks, nicotine, tobacco

So I don't smoke but I am wondering if someone were to say smoke about 10 cigarettes per year from about age 20 to age 70, would it affect their health in any way? Would they still be more prone to lung cancer, ventilators, diseases, chronic cough, etc.?

Comment: http://www.health.harvard.edu/mens-health/light-smoking-dangerous-in-any-dose